# How to crawl data from encrypted url?

Tags: forms, url, scrapy

I'm trying to use scrapy to collect the university's professors' contact information from its directory. Since I can't post more than 2 links, I put all links in the [following picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX5ZH.png).

I set last name equals from the drop-down menu as shown in the picture. Then I search all professors by last name.

Usually, the url will have some pattern from other universities' website. However, for this one, the original url is (1). It becomes (2)when I search 'An' as last name. It seems like 'An' is replaced by something like  529385FD5FF90A198625819E002B8B41? I'm not sure. Is there any way I can get the url that I need to send as a request? I mean, this time I search 'An'. If I search another last name like Lee. It will be another request. They are irregular. I can't find a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scraper is not as complex as you think it is. It just makes a POST call from the form and that returns a GET request. Below would work

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class univSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "univ"
    start_urls = ["http://appl103.lsu.edu/dir003.nsf/(NoteID)/5903C096337C2AA28625819E0038E3E4?OpenDocument"]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response, formname="_DIRVNAM", formdata={"LastName": "Lalwani"},callback = self.search_result)

    def search_result(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        print(response.body)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have 2 questions. Q1: Where do you find the form data? My friend showed me I can find it in network somewhere. But I can't find it in this website. Q2: open_in_browser(response), is it just for showing me how it works? I don't actually need to open browser when crawling?

Comment: Q1, yes I just checked in Firefox disabling JS and it worked, which meant the ID is not being calculated but there on form. Q2: Yes that was just to show you the response, you wont use it as such

Comment: Q1: I used Chrome but can't find the form. Maybe I should try firefox :)